# Use iTextSharp (.net) to resize pdf with text

Tags: .net, itext

I have a PDF with texts embedded on an image (TIF converted to PDF by OCR engine). The size is standard size (e.g. A4, i.e., 21cm x 29.7 cm).
However, I would like to resize the pdf to add a margin (e.g. 1.5cm) at the left of the page.

I know I can use PdfContentByte.AddTemplate(template of size 18.5cmx28.85cm) to do so (see below).

However, this will also reduce the size of the template as well as the image. If I replace the image on the page, the image will only be of size 18.5cmx28.85cm, not 21cmx29.7cm.

How can I resize the page (actually the texts) other than using AddTemplate? Thanks.

Using Windows 10, .Net framework v4.6.2, iTextSharp 5.5.10

```
    float fRes = 300f; // resolution of the image
    float fMargin = 0.6f // margin=0.6in=1.5cm

    PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader([Original file]);
    int iPageCount = objReader.NumberOfPages();
    Rectangle rect = objReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    System.Drawing.Size sz = new System.Drawing.Size((int)Utilities.PointsToInches(rect.Right) * fRes), (int)Utilities.PointsToInches(rect.Top) * fRes));
    float fWidth = sz.Width / fRes, fScale = (fWidth - fMargin) / fWidth, fScaleXY = (float)sz.Width/(float)sz.Height;
    double dX = 0, dY = 0;
    Document doc = new Document(rect, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream([New file], FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();
    for (int I = 0; I <= iPageCount; I++)
    {
        PDfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(objReader, I);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        dX = Utilities.InchesToPoints(fMargin);
        dY = Utilities.InchesToPoints(fMargin * fScaleXY);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, fScale, 0, 0, fScale, dX, dY);
        if (I < iPageCount)
            doc.NewPage();
    }

    doc.Close();
    writer.Close();
    objReader.Close();
```

Comment: Would enlarging the page by 1.5cm to the left be ok? E.g. making a non-standard 22.5cm x 29.7cm out of an A4 21cm x 29.7cm.

Comment: Hi, it is not ok because the replacing image may have contents outside the template (18.5cmx28.85cm). Even I change the size of the original pdf or the replacing TIF, those content cannot be addressed. It is not a size problem but it is a content problem.

Comment: In short, I want to treat the text and image separately: shrink the texts while maintain the size of image, so that I can replace the image with another one.

Comment: Shrink text at its current position?

Comment: Nop. Shrink and move text. E.g. if the text is at the (1,1) cm of the page, it will then moved to (2.5, 3.12) cm of the page and reduced a bit in size.